# kafka 8 and memory - There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using DigiOcean instance with 512 megs of ram,  I get the below error with kafka.
I am not a java proficient dev.  How do I adjust kafka to utilize the small amount of ram.  This is a dev sever.  I dont want to pay more per hour for a bigger machine.

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 986513408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid6500.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000bad30000, 986513408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can adjust the JVM heap size by editing `kafka-server-start.sh`, `zookeeper-server-start.sh`and so on:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"
```

The `-Xms` parameter specifies the minimum heap size. To get your server to at least start up, try changing it to use less memory. Given that you only have 512M, you should change the maximum heap size (`-Xmx`) too:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M"
```

I'm not sure what the minimal memory requirements of kafka in default config are - maybe you need to adjust the message size in kafka to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

Area: HotSpot / gc

Synopsis

```
Crashes due to failure to allocate large pages.

On Linux, failures when allocating large pages can lead to crashes. When running JDK 7u51 or later versions, the issue can be recognized in two ways:

    Before the crash happens, one or more lines similar to the following example will have been printed to the log:

    os::commit_memory(0x00000006b1600000, 352321536, 2097152, 0) failed;
    error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12); Cannot allocate large pages, 
    falling back to regular pages

    If a file named hs_err is generated, it will contain a line similar to the following example:

    Large page allocation failures have occurred 3 times

The problem can be avoided by running with large page support turned off, for example, by passing the "-XX:-UseLargePages" option to the java binary.
```

Answer (score 1):

add environment variable JAVA_OPTS.

In Linux, edit ~/.bashrc file, and better source it.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms128M -Xmx128M"
```

In widows, add system variable

```
JAVA_OPTS "-Xms128M -Xmx128M"
```

and then reboot.

And if it does not work, many file should be changed, e.x. **bin/kafka-server-start.sh**,**config/server.properties**. Decrease number in those files.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was previously doing android development having the android studio and a virtual machine running for an entire night I realized this error when I tried to start my apache Kafka server.
I  restarted my laptop to reset memory and then started Kafka server all over again hope this helps someone out there!..

Answer (score 0):

In your environment path change the java path to JDK64 instead on JDK32. This solved my issue where i was having 64gb ram and using 32bit Jvm changing the path to JDK64(64bit JVM) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450241/5226835) can be used also to solve the same problem in a **Docker container running Kafka**.

Just add the following ENV variable to your docker-compose file (or run script):

```
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xmx512M -Xms256M"
```

Of course you should fine tune the values on your hosting machine resource availability

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error on AWS. I figured I needed a t2.medium at least for my broker and zookeeper to work.