# kafka - proper way to set java startup params

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

There seem to be conflicting schools of thought when it comes to setting the various heap, GC, etc java params for a **Kafka** process.

One group says to edit the `kafka-server-start` bash file

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448907/kafka-8-and-memory-there-is-insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environme/21450241#21450241)

Another group says to set a system var and let the kafka startup pick it up

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681511/how-do-i-set-the-java-options-for-kafka)

In the latest instructions from Confluent the follow 'recommendations' appear:

```
-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
   -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
   -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80
```

What's the *official Confluent party-line* on where to set these? (I assume the defaults don't use these to accommodate smaller test machines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these things are essentially telling you to do the same thing, which is manually overriding the value of `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`.

It looks like [this is what you are looking for](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-server-start.sh) from `kafka-server-start.sh`

```
if [ "x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"
fi

EXTRA_ARGS=${EXTRA_ARGS-'-name kafkaServer -loggc'}
```

If you are starting this from the command line, you can call

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms2g"
./kafka-server-start.sh
```

Or, if you are editing the startup script first, you do not need to `export`, because the variable is used locally.

```
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms2g"
if [ "x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"
fi
```

The benefit of the first, is that it does not require changes to kafka-source, and allows for the environment to be configured via just shell variables;

The second is convenient in that you do not need to remember to setup your environment variables before starting the server.